# Symfony 2.4 multiple file upload

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.4

How can I upload multiple images using only one file widget? Currently I have disabled mapping for the images (otherwise it would try to map to the values of the object, but then it would complain in the view because it's an array), but I have no idea how to get them back into the service.images array. What would be the best solution to this?

**Service class**

```
/**
 * Service
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="services")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="xxx\SiteBundle\Entity\ServiceTranslation")
 */
class Service
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="xxx\SiteBundle\Entity\ServiceTranslation",
     *  mappedBy="object",
     *  cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    private $translations;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="xxx\SiteBundle\Entity\Image", mappedBy="service",
     *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    private $images;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translations = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // everything else

}
```

**Image class:**

```
    /**
     * Image class.
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="images")
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @Gedmo\Uploadable(filenameGenerator="SHA1", allowOverwrite=true, appendNumber=true)
     */
    class Image
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         * @Gedmo\UploadableFileName
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         * @Gedmo\UploadableFilePath
         */
        private $path;

        /**
         * @var
         */
        private $file;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="xxx\SiteBundle\Entity\Service", inversedBy="images")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         *
         */
        private $service;

        // everything else
}
```

**Service form type:**

```
$builder
    ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', array(
        'translatable_class' => 'xxx\SiteBundle\Entity\Service',
        'label'  => false,
        'fields' => array(
            'name' => array(),
            'price' => array(
                'locale_options' => array(
                    'lt' => array(
                        'display' => false,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'description' => array(),
        ),
    ))
    ->add('images', 'file', array(
        'data_class' => 'xxx\SiteBundle\Entity\Image',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array(
            'accept' => 'image/*',
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
        ),
        'mapped' => false,
    ))
;
```

**Controller**

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

    $uploadableManager = $this->get('stof_doctrine_extensions.uploadable.manager');

    foreach ($service->getImages() as $image) {
        $uploadableManager->markEntityToUpload(
            $image,
            $image->getFile()
        );
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($service);
    $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it seems I got it working.

```
$files = $request->files->get($form->getName());
foreach ($files['images'] as $imageData) {
    $image = new Image();

    $uploadableManager->markEntityToUpload(
        $image,
        $imageData
    );

    $em->persist($image);
}
```

Yeah, it doesn't look so good, but works..

Comment: Thank you for being helpful... I would suggest to to give more details of the actions to be done on your controller.

Answer (score 0):

One additional detail to save others some time: You should set the attribute *multiple* as a boolean value in the options of the file field instead of setting it manually as an 'attr':

```
->add('images', 'file', array(
    'data_class' => 'xxx\SiteBundle\Entity\Image',
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => array(
        'accept' => 'image/*'
    ),
    'multiple' => true,
    'mapped' => false,
))
```

This change ensures *$files['images']* to be in array in any case, because when I select only 1 image, the object is returned without an array and I could not iterate over it with *foreach*.